# Sorting listbox by user defined criteria - delphi xe6

Tags: ios, delphi, listbox, delphi-xe6

I am trying to implement my own sorting feature for a Listbox. What I am wanting to do is, sort items within a listbox depending upon the chosen criteria, whether based on for example, criteria1,criteria2,criteria3... and so on.

I have these, lets call them randomObjects that act as records for the data.
These random objects look like this:

```
type
  randomObject = class(TObject)
    ID,
    criteria1,
    criteria2,
    criteria3:String;
  end;
```

Here is the function I call when wanting to sort the randomObjects in the listbox:

```
procedure TmyForm.sortME(criteria: string; asc: Boolean);
var
  tempList,pList:TStringList;
  p:part;
  i:integer;
  item:TListBoxItem;
begin
  tempList := TStringList.Create;
  for p in AllRandomObjects do //allRandomObjects is an array of RandomObject
    if criteria = 'Criteria1' then
      tempList.Append(p.Criteria1)
    else if criteria = 'Criteria2' then
      tempList.Append(p.Criteria2)
    else if criteria = 'Criteria3' then
      tempList.Append(p.criteria3);

  Plist:= TStringList.Create; //pList to keep track of original order to reference the RandomObjects
  plist.Text := tempList.Text;
  if asc then
    tempList.Sorted:=true //create new order
  else
    tempList.CustomSort(StringListSortCompare); //create new order

  listbox.BeginUpdate;
  listbox.Items.Clear;
  for i := 0 to tempList.Count-1 do
  begin
    p := AllRandomObjects[plist.IndexOf(tempList.Strings[i])];
    Listbox.Items.Append('');
    item := Listbox.ListItems[Listbox.Items.Count-1];
    //blah-blah, create text objects to add to the item for displaying
    end;
  end;
  listbox.EndUpdate;

end;
```

This takes very long however ( at least a few seconds, which seems like forever when on mobile ).
Just learning, I'm sure there is a better/faster/more efficient way of doing this. Please help or give guidance!. Thanks! Developing for iOS, FMX Delphi xe6

Comment: What part is slow? The GUI part? Sounds to me as though you need virtual list. How can you ask about perf without giving any details. I bet your code runs fine with just 10 entries. Perhaps you have more. How can we tell?

Comment: About 500 entries. I'm sure it's not the loading of the GUI, when I initially create the list there's no lag.  I see suggestions in other SO posts about using virtualLB/virtualTree but is that for FMX as well as VCL? I don't see an onData event (yet at least).

Comment: The core of my question was about how to improve my code, or if there were any built-in functions/methods I should be using instead, so if you say my code should be fine then I will double check to make sure it just isn't because I'm loading/sorting a lot of entries at once.

Comment: You need to know which part is slow. Please find that out. You might also find an enum to be better suited to specify criteria.

Comment: That is the slow part `plist.IndexOf` because of an unordered stringlist. There are different [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Classes.TStringList.IndexOf) behaviors if sorted or not

Comment: It would be better to use a temp. [list to sort](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Sort) or add the instances to the sorted stringlist [`TStringList.AddObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStringList.AddObject)

Comment: As I can see in your code, `plist` is not sorted, so each time when you call `plist.IndexOf` your app enumerates in average half of the items instead of using faster algorithm. `plist.Sorted := True` and `plist.Find` instead of `plist.IndexOf`.

Comment: @Abelisto `plist` cannot be sorted in this case, because it is used as a lookup to the actual array index of the corresponding instance

Comment: @SirRufo in the unit `IniFiles` exists some interest class `THashedStringList`. Any questions to Borland's programmers :-) This class does not breaks strings order but finds needed string much faster.

Comment: @Abelisto Look at my answer, that is the *direct* way to go :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sort the array itself with [`System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Sort`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Sort) and iterate over the array to populate the data to the listbox.

```
uses
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.Generics.Defaults,
  System.StrUtils;

procedure TmyForm.sortME( criteria: string; asc: Boolean );
var
  LCriteriaIndex : Integer;
  LData : TList<randomObject>;
begin
  LCriteriaIndex := IndexText( criteria, ['criteria1', 'criteria2', 'criteria3'] );

  if LCriteriaIndex < 0 then
    raise EArgumentException.Create( 'unknown criteria' );

  LData := TList<randomObject>.Create( TComparer<randomObject>.Construct(
        function( const L, R : randomObject ) : Integer
    begin
      case LCriteriaIndex of
        0 :
          Result := CompareText( L.criteria1, R.criteria1 ); 
        1 :
          Result := CompareText( L.criteria2, R.criteria2 );
        2 :
          Result := CompareText( L.criteria3, R.criteria3 );
      end;

      if not asc
      then
        Result := -Result;
    end ) );

  LData.AddRange( AllRandomObjects );
  LData.Sort;

  showData( LData.ToArray );
end;

procedure TmyForm.showData( AData : TArray<randomObject> );
var
  LData : randomObject;
  LItem : TListBoxItem;
begin
  listbox.BeginUpdate;
  try
    listbox.Clear;
    for LData in AData do
    begin
      LItem := TListBoxItem.Create( listbox );

      //blah-blah, create text objects to add to the item for displaying

      listbox.AddObject( LItem );
    end;
  finally
    listbox.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This destroys the source array which may not be desirable. An alternative is to create an array of indices, `0, 1, 2, ..., high(AllRandomObjects)` and sort that according to the desired criteria. That is most similar to the idea in the question.

Comment: To leave the original array order untouched I updated my answer